# Publishing MVC project Via FTP via Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ftp, asp.net-mvc-5, hosting

I am trying to copy my project to server which does not have web deploy. (tsohost- if am wrong). So the only option i have left is FTP. Somehow when i do this with VS 2013 it skips my database (mdf file) and few folders in Content. The page works after publish but functionally based on database is of course gone. The question is whether there is some way around this to deploy full solution via FTP?
It's MVC 5 working on .NET 4.5 on Windows 2012 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I'm being Captain Obvious, but do you have your .mdf database in the `App_Data` folder? And do the content files' properties have **Copy to Output Directory** = **Copy always**?

[image]

Comment: What I did is set Items to deploy -> All files in this project in all configurations. Is that correct ? And database is in App_Data.

Comment: Sounds right, then! I might check the "Copy to Output Directory" settings for those files, too. I know that selecting "Items to deploy -> All files in this project" like you did copies files [regardless of Build Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#why_dont_all_files_get_deployed)...but I don't know if it's regardless of the "Copy to Output Directory" setting, too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the reason. When selecting Items to deploy it needed to be **All Files in this Project Folder** not All Files in this Project. Then it copied all the Content with no problem.